# Make itemBuilder run every time without calling setState()

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having a code like this for `PageView.builder`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return PageView.builder(
    itemCount: myList.length,
    onPageChanged: (int pageIndex) => setState(() => index = pageIndex), // this make it work fine
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyPage(myList[index])
  );
}
```

The problem with this `itemBuilder` (of `PageView.builder`) and normal `itemBuilder` (of `ListView.builder`) is that they stop getting called once they have drawn the widget on the screen for previous `index` value.

Now in my use case, I want this `itemBuilder` to fire every time the Page has changed in the `PageView` because I am updating `list` and now I want to show new data in MyPage for new `list`. How to do that?

---

PS: There is `onPageChanged()` callback and I can use `setState()` in that, it works fine but it simply ruins the purpose of `PageView` OR is it okay to use `setState()` in `onPageChanged()`, wont' that be redundant?

Comment: so you have to rebuild your `PageView` as there is no "animated" alternative like `AnimatedList` for static `ListView`

Comment: So, I ended up calling setState() to solve the issue. Not a nice solution but worked for me.

Comment: you dont have to use any `onPageChanged` and call `setState` - just make sure `PageView` is rebuilt - like [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/fx8ZBync)

Comment: @pskink I am sorry, I didn't quite try it yet, I am still using my solution of calling `setState()` from `onPageChanged()`.